# could not find implicit value for parameter um: akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[class]

Tags: akka, akka-http

i am new to akka http and i am having difficulty in marshalling and un-marshalling  of my case class
here is my code

```
case class Event(uuid:String)

//main class 
class demo {

    val route: Route =

    post {
            path("create-event") {
              entity(as[Event]) { event =>
                  complete("event created")
                }
              }
            }
          }
    }
```

i am getting a compile time error on this line

```
entity(as[Event]) { event =>

 could not find implicit value for parameter um: akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[models.event.Event]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Akka-Http uses spray to marshal and unmarshal json and the error is because no implicit converter which is used for conversion is defined.

```
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport
import spray.json._

trait EventProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val eventJsonFormat = jsonFormat1(Event)
}

class demo extends SprayJsonSupport with EventProtocol {
// your code
}
```

The detailed steps are provided in akka-http [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/json-support.html)

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way to solve this. akka-http-jackson has an implementation for Request Unmarshaller.

sbt add lib:

```
"de.heikoseeberger"                         %% "akka-http-jackson"             % "1.27.0"
```

and then in your code

```
import de.heikoseeberger.akkahttpjackson.JacksonSupport._
```